# SKBitmapFont in SKLabelNode - finally a support for bitmap fonts?

Tags: sprite-kit, bitmap-fonts

Is Apple finally adding support for bitmap fonts? I was debugging today and saw a _bmf property of type SKBitmapFont in SKLabelNode.

Comment: nope not yet unfortunatly

Comment: actually if you look at a class dump the SKBitmapFont has been there all along just apple is withholding it